# Add new Admob campaign without a Destination URL?

Tags: admob, google-ads-api

In the AdMob console, a Destination URL is required (unable to create an Ad Campaign without one).

Is it possible to create either an App or Website Campaign without a Destination URL?

I need to publish a new campaign with an Ad that is used *for information only*. When a user sees and clicks the ad within the app (iOS and Android), he or she should not be able be redirected to an external website. The user only needs to be able to see the contents of the ad without further action.

I am not concerned with Android and iOS specific code implementations. This is work that needs to be completed within the AdMob console.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this is a feature. The whole process is set up around clicks with a huge chunk of advertisers actually paying per click. Google themselves also monitor quality of ads based on click-through rates etc. & use that data to influence which ad gets the impression when an ad slot is loaded. I had a quick look at their docs and couldn't find anything definitive but I'd be astounded if such an advertising model were possible through admob.

Comment: @Stewart_R -- Thanks for checking. I agree, it doesn't seem possible. If anything, my use case is a misuse case.